# Can theme() call a theme function from another module?

Tags: theming

In a module I created, can I add a call to `theme()` similar to `theme('example_def', $var)` where example_def is a theme function defined from another module?

```
function def_theme() {
return array(
  'example_def' => array(
    'arguments' => array('nid' => NULL)
  ));
}

function theme_example_def() {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a module can call, with `theme()`, a theme function that is defined from another module. If it were not so, no module could use [theme_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7), since that is defined as one of the System module theme functions. This is contrary to Drupal philosophy; limiting a module to use the theme functions it defines would not make sense.

See [system_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_theme/7) which calls [drupal_common_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_common_theme/7) to add link to the theme function it *implements*.

```
function drupal_common_theme() {
  return array(

    // From theme.inc.
    'html' => array(
      'render element' => 'page',
      'template' => 'html',
    ),
    'page' => array(
      'render element' => 'page',
      'template' => 'page',
    ),
    'region' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'region',
    ),
    'status_messages' => array(
      'variables' => array('display' => NULL),
    ),
    'link' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'text' => NULL,
        'path' => NULL,
        'options' => array(),
      ),
    ),
    // …
  );
}
```

Notice that the correct theme function definition that works for Drupal 7 is the following one; the one you are using is only for Drupal 6 or previous versions.

```
function def_theme() {
  return array(
    'example_def' => array(
      'variables' => array('nid' => NULL)
    )
  );
}
```

Since your example of calling the function is `theme('example_def', $var)`, I take you are using Drupal 7, for which your definition would not work.